# Existence of surjective but not injective morphism between rings imply being non isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let R and R' be two rings and we already know that they are isomorphic if there is a one to one and onto map between them (of course this map is a ring homomorphism). I have a question at this point.

> If we find a surjective but not injective ring morphism between R and R', can we directly say they are not isomorphic?

For example, let $k$ be a field and $k[x,y]$ be polynomial ring with two variables. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $xy-1$. I want to show $\frac{k[x,y]}{I}$ is not isomorphic to $k[x]$.

Let $\phi:\frac{k[x,y]}{I} \rightarrow k[x]$ map $f(x)+I$ to $f(x)$. Easily one can show $\phi$ is surjective. However, for example, $x+y+I$ has image $h(x)$, so $\phi(x+y+I)=\phi(h(x)+I)$, by showing $x+y-h(x) \notin I$, we can show $\phi$ is not injective. Can we say $\frac{k[x,y]}{I}$ is not isomorphic to $k[x]$.

Comment: Where does your $\phi$ map $y+I$?

Comment: I don't care the image of $y+I$. It mapped to some h(x)

Comment: What do you mean that you don't care? You have to check additivity and multiplicativity of $\phi$ if you want it to be a homomorphism!

Comment: Sorry Gae, I made a mistake by ignoring $y+I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the existence of a surjective but non-injective ring homomorphism does not imply that two rings are not isomorphic. Consider e.g. the ring $\mathbb{Z}(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ of integer polynomials on countably many variables and the map that sends $x_1$ to itself and any other variable $x_j$ to $x_{j-1}$. This results in a surjective but non-injective ring homomorphism, yet any ring is isomorphic with itself.