# Prove $\frac{k[x,y]}{I}$ and $k[x]$ are not isomorphic where $I=<xy-1>$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

This question is related to my previous question [Existence of surjective but not injective map between rings imply being non isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928883/existence-of-surjective-but-not-injective-map-between-rings-imply-being-non-isom)

Here my question is, how can i show $\frac{k[x,y]}{I}$ and $k[x]$ are not isomorphic. I showed there exist a ring hom. which is surjective but not injective. However this is not enough to prove the being non isomorphic.

Comment: You can show that there are many more invertible elements in $k[X,Y]/I$ than in $k[X,Y]$.

Comment: I'm not sure there are surjective ring homomorphisms $k[x,y]/I\to k[x]$ or $k[x]\to k[x,y]/I$.

Comment: Do you consider those rings as $k$-algebras (so, must your homomorphisms be the identity on $k$) or as general rings (allowing, for instance, $x \in k[x]$ to map to an element of $k$)?

Comment: Hi Gae, I showed a surjective map in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928883/existence-of-surjective-but-not-injective-map-between-rings-imply-being-non-isom

Comment: Thank you lisyarus, I noticed that y is inverse of x in the quotient ring.

Comment: Can we say that If $\phi: k[x,y]/I \rightarrow k[x]$, then $\phi(x+I)$ must be constant since $x+I$ is invertible. And similarly $\phi(y+I)$ is also. So such a map cannot map any element to a nonconstant polynomial in $k[x]$?

Comment: @RedPhoenix Correct. In fact, for any $k$-algebra $A$, the ($k$-algebra) homomorphisms $\phi: k[X,Y]/\langle XY-1 \rangle \rightarrow A$ are in one-to-one correspondence with invertible elements of $A$ ($\phi$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(X)$, which has to be invertible). In your case, the invertible elements of $A=k[X]$ are just constant polynomials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're considering your rings as $k$-algebras, the argument is easy.

Suppose $\phi \colon k[x,y]/(xy-1) \to k[x]$ is a $k$-algebra isomorphism. Because $\bar x$ is invertible, its image $\phi(\bar x)$ is invertible as well. But $k[x]^* = k^*$, so $\phi(\bar x) \in k^*$. This contradicts the fact the $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras.

If you're considering your rings as general rings, it takes a bit more work to derive a contradication from $\phi(\bar x) \in k^*$.

After you conclude that $\phi(\bar x) \in k^*$, look at $\phi(1 + \bar x)$. Note that $\phi(1 + \bar x) = 1 +\phi(\bar x) \in k$. Now there are two cases: either $1 + \phi(\bar x) \in k^*$ or $1 + \phi(\bar x) = 0$. The first case gives a contradiction because $1 + \bar x$ is not invertible in $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$, so its image under $\phi$ also cannot be invertible. The second case gives a contradiction because it means that $\phi(\bar x) = -1$ and therefore $\bar x = -1$, which is not the case.

As an aside, to see that $1 + \bar x$ is not invertible, consider the $k$-algebra homomorphism from $k[x,y]/(xy - 1)$ to $k$ induced by $x \mapsto -1$ and $y \mapsto -1$. (Note that this is a homomorphism because $xy - 1 \mapsto 0$). Under this homomorphism $1 + \bar x$ maps to $0$, which is not invertible, so $1 + \bar x$ is not invertible either.

Comment: Thank you so much Magdiragdag! That is perfect solution.

Comment: I'm not able to prove that $1 +\overline{x}$ is not invertible in $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$. How do you do it? I tried to consider an inverse $\overline{z}$ and derive a contradiction... With no success so far.

Comment: The trick is to realize that invertible elements stay invertible under evaluation at particular values for $x$ and $y$. Now if you evaluate $1 + \bar x$ at $\bar x = -1$, you get $0$, which is not invertible. You have to be a bit careful with the 'evaluation'; see the updated answer for details.